# Remove part of string with multiple occurences inside cell

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have the following dataframe:

```
bla = data.frame(mycol = "bla_v2_2072|ID:61462952|;bla_v2_0113|ID:61460993|")
```

and I want to remove everything after the first '|', but the cell contains basically two substrings separated by ';'.

Now, I tried

```
gsub("\\|.*","",bla$mycol)
```

which gives me `bla_v2_2072`, but what I expect is

```
bla_v2_2072;bla_v2_0113
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gsub()`:

```
bla$mycol <- gsub("(\\|.*?(?=;))|(\\|[^;]*$)", "", bla$mycol, perl = TRUE)
```

Or using the same regex pattern in tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

bla %>% 
  mutate(mycol = str_remove_all(mycol, "(\\|.*?(?=;))|(\\|[^;]*$)"))
```

Result:

```
                    mycol
1 bla_v2_2072;bla_v2_0113
```

Explanation:

```
"(\\|.*?(?=;))              # literal '|' and following characters up to next ';'
              |             # or
               (\\|[^;]*$)" # literal '|' through end of string if no intervening ';'
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
bla %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(mycol, delim = ";") %>% 
   reframe(mycol = str_c(str_remove(mycol, "\\|.*"), 
   collapse = ";"), .by = 'rn') %>%
  select(-rn)
```

-output

```
                   mycol
1 bla_v2_2072;bla_v2_0113
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
gsub("(\\w+)(\\|ID:\\d+\\|)", "\\1", bla$mycol)
[1] "bla_v2_2072;bla_v2_0113"
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
gsub("\\|[^|]+\\|", "", bla$mycol)
#> [1] "bla_v2_2072;bla_v2_0113"
```

pattern explanation: escaped "|" followed by everything not "|" at least one time then one more "|"

Answer (score -1):

You can first separate your string by ";" and then remove everything after "|". Finally, concatenate them back using `paste0`.

```
> paste0(sub("\\|.*","", unlist(strsplit(bla$mycol, split=";"))), collapse = "; ")
[1] "bla_v2_2072; bla_v2_0113"
```

Comment: a yes, I understand, but then they again need to be concatenated by `;`